# Sum of n^2 greater than the sum of any compositions of n squared?

Tags: calculus

Is there any proof that $n^2$ is greater than the sum of invidual quadratics of ${k_i}$, where the sum of $k_i$ equals to $n$? $n$ and $k$ are considered to be positive Integers.

Equivalently, is it true that: $n^2>\sum k_i^2$, with $\sum_i k_i=n$?

Comment: We have $0 = (-1) + (1)$, but $0^2 < (-1)^2 + (1)^2$. I think you need a few specifications here to get to the problem you actually want to ask about.

Comment: $\sum k_i = n \implies n^2 - \sum k_i^2 = \sum (n-k_i) k_i$

Answer (score 0):

I think the proof is straigthforward. Let $\sum_i k_i=n$. Then, it readily follows that $n^2=(\sum_i k_i)^2\geq\sum_i k_i^2$ assuming that $n,k_i>0$.

Comment: The inequality should be the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

I add two assumptions:

- The $k_i$ are non-negative (consider $n=1$, $k_1=2$, $k_2=-1$, where the conclusion does not hold);
- You also accept equality, that is, you want to show $n^2\geq\sum k_i^2$ (take $k_1=0$, $k_2=n$, for which you have equality).

Then what you want to prove is equivalent to
$$\sum\frac{k_i}{n}=1\implies \sum\left(\frac{k_i}{n}\right)^2\leq 1.$$

But this is clear, because if $\sum\frac{k_i}{n}=1$, then $0\leq\frac{k_i}{n}\leq 1$, yielding $\left(\frac{k_i}{n}\right)^2\leq \frac{k_i}{n}$, from which the result follows.